# Atomically grab multiple locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Assume we have to undertake a transfer between any 2 accounts(among hunders out there) as part of a transaction.
And there would be multiple similar transactions running concurrently in a typical multi-threaded environment.
Usual convention would be as below(maintaining the lock order as per a pre-designed convention):

```
lock account A
lock account B
transfer(A,B)
release B
release A
```

Is there any way to attempt the locks and release as an atomic operation?

Comment: sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: It's the classic deadlock situation when someone else locks in the reverse order. Atomic or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is: you need to lock the locks under a lock. In other words, you need to create a lock hierarchy. But this solution is not very efficient because it decreases lock granularity.

It looks like in your case it would be sufficient to always take locks in the same order. For example always lock user with lesser ID first.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction is atomic by ACID definition (A - for atomicity). Isolation (at least `READ_COMMITED` one) guarantee that other transaction that may occur for account A at the same time will wait while previous started transaction will be finished. So actually, you don't need to lock them explicitly as they will lock by internal implementation (database for example) and that locks will be more efficient as they can use optimistic locking techniques.

But this is only true if they all participating in one transactional context (like in `JTA` environment for example). In such environment you could just start transaction in the beginning of transfer method and no need for locking Account A and Account B.

In case, that they are not in the same transactional context, you can introduce some another locking object but this will significantly reduce performance as threads will be locked even though one is working with accounts A and B and another one with accounts C and D. There are techniques in how to avoid this situation (see `ConcurentHashMap` for example, where
locks are on baskets - and not on the whole object).

But with your particular example answer could only be some general thoughts as example is to short to examine more. I think variant with locking account A and account B in particular order (should be very care with that - as this could lead to potential deadlocks. And assuming there is not just transfer method that could work with them - it is really high risky) is normal for given situation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP used the word transaction to mean transfer. This question is not about database or distributed transactions.

Comment: @Oleg yes, it is not. It is about getting atomic lock on some method. I just pointed out that in transaction that is actually not even necessary (database and distributed transactions were just examples not the subject of the answer). And only way in non-transactional environment is to introduce another locking object, so the answer is given in it itself. With just additional information that could be relevant to author or others. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: Don't know, probably nothing, just feels somewhat unrelated. You convinced me enough to remove the downvote.

Comment: Apparently I can't do that unless you edit the answer.

Comment: @Oleg I understands that it could seems unrelated - will take that point into account for next time. I was triggered by transaction mentioning in the qestion. (and I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code.
Note: it only work for two locks and I'm unsure how to make it scale to more locks.
The idea is that you take the first lock and you try to take the second one.
If it fails, we know that 1 lock is free right now, but the other is busy.
Thus we release the first lock and you invert them, so we will lock on the one that was busy and try to take the one that (WAS!) free, if it is still free.
Rinse and repeat.
There is a statistically impossibility that this code will go in StackOverflow, 
I think handling it and giving an error is better than making it loop, since it would be a signal that something somewhere is going very wrong.

```
public static void takeBoth(ReentrantLock l1,ReentrantLock l2) {
    l1.lock();
    if(l2.tryLock()) {return;}
    l1.unlock();
    try{takeBoth(l2,l1);}
    catch(StackOverflowError e) {throw new Error("??");}
  }
  public static void releaseBoth(ReentrantLock l1,ReentrantLock l2){
    if(!l1.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {l1.unlock();}//this will fail: IllegarMonitorState exception
    l2.unlock();//this may fail, in that case we did not touch l1.
    l1.unlock();    
    }
```